# How to change number format in Logstash

Tags: logstash

I have numbers like

```
1.553
23
2.383
26
566
```

When I parse this with logstash, I get string value of these.

When I try to use mutate filter plugin like below;

```
mutate {
     convert => {
            "number_field" => "integer"
      }
}
```

It returns wrong.

I mean as an example,**2.383 as input goes 2 as output**.

My expections is below

```
1553
23
2383
566
```

How can i solve this ?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [mutate+convert](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert) is used to convert to integer it will truncate floats. You can use integer_eu to tell it that the a dot is used instead of a comma to separate thousands (e.g., "1.000" produces an integer with value of one thousand).